# Qt dependencies in a deb package

Tags: qt, ubuntu, deb, launchpad

When creating a `.deb` package I create a file named `control` that contains some fields:

```
Package: my-qt-app-name
Version: 0.01
Architecture: all
Maintainer: my name <my email address>
Installed-Size: 2
Depends: ??????
Section: extras
Priority: optional
Homepage: my homepage
Description: some description
```

You see the field named `Depends`. To be sure that my application will work on another computer that runs Ubuntu (or one of its distributions) what value must has this field?

My Qt version is `5.1.1`.

The first lines from `main.cpp` contain:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QWebView>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QDir>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWebPage>
#include <QObject>
```

Comment: What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: @NicholasSmith My Qt version is `5.1.1`.

Comment: depends on which features of qt you are using.. There are a lot of

Comment: @hek2mgl Do you mean what libraries do I use? I added the first lines from my cpp file.

Comment: yeah. check `virtualbox-qt` for example. It depends on the qt packages `libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3), libqt4-opengl (>= 4:4.7.2), libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0), libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0)` (on my ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: @hek2mgl I tried that. The package was installed successfully but when I run my application I get this error: "app-name: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5WebKitWidgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" (like before)... Is possible to fix this error by providing the correct dependencies in `Depends` field from `control` file?

Comment: Try `libqtwebkit5` or `libqt5-webkit`... Btw, why don't you know that? you should know that from compile time experience...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40524/discussion-between-john--and-hek2mgl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the problem adding the following libraries to the debian `control` file:

```
Depends: libqt5webkit5-dev, qtquick1-5-dev, qtlocation5-dev, qtsensors5-dev, qtdeclarative5-dev, libsqlite3-dev
```

Finally my problem is fixed.

Comment: Finally you figured it out ;) +1

Answer (score 2):

With debhelper string Depends: will be look like this

Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}

From [Introduction to Debian Packaging](https://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging)

"Depends:"

field lists the packages that must be installed for the program in the binary package to work. Listing such dependencies manually is tedious, error-prone work. To make this work, the ${shlibs:Depends} magic bit needs to be in there. The other magic stuff is there for debhelper. The {misc:Depends} bit. The shlibs magic is for shared library dependencies, the misc magic is for some stuff debhelper does. For other dependencies, you need to add them manually to Depends or Build-Depends and the ${...} magic bits only work in Depends

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Debhelper packaging tools, the build process can automatically detect any dependencies of your package incurred by dynamic library linking, using wrappers around the `dpkg-shlibdeps` tool, and fill them in to your `debian/control` file for you.

Comment: Can you explain more how can I do that...?

Comment: To give a very good answer would take far more space than these comments allow, but see the tutorial at https://wiki.debian.org/IntroDebianPackaging for a good overview and introduction.

Answer (score 0):

You need the package `libqt5webkit5` as a dependency

Comment: Some more libraries were needed. Now, it [works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20451625/1420197)! :-)